How do I set the deploy target for swift-create-xcframework?
I am building a Swift Package (without dependencies) to be included in iOS and tvOS applications (from iOS/tvOS 14 onwards). My Package.swift looks as follows:
// swift-tools-version: 5.9
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "FooPackage",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v14),
        .tvOS(.v14)  // Add tvOS support
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, making them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "FooPackage",
            type: .dynamic,
            targets: ["FooPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package, defining a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package and products from dependencies.
        .target(
            name: "FooPackage"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "FooPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["FooPackage"]),
    ]
)

I found out that it is rather complicated to generate a Swift Package-based XCFramework, but there is a tool that helps with that: swift-create-xcframework.
I am able to build the XCFramework (which I can include in my app projects as a dependency) using:
swift create-xcframework \
  --platform ios \
  --platform tvos \
  --output build/FooPackage.xcframework \
  --zip \
  --zip-version "$VERSION"

This creates the ZIP file just fine. I can use it in an app that I build for iOS 17.5.
Yet, when I use that app on a device with an older iOS version, I get a crash:
standard 12:03:04.331965+0200 ReportCrash ASI found [dyld] (sensitive) 'Symbol not found: _$sSa034_makeUniqueAndReserveCapacityIfNotB0yyFyXl_Ts5
  Referenced from: <7380A608-51AC-3AF4-B115-292D5A29B497> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2A2D8EDA-7188-4229-B6E0-541B8FF3BEC9/SomeApp.app/Frameworks/FooPackage.framework/FooPackage (built for iOS 17.5 which is newer than running OS)
  Expected in:     <5F6B7D24-C88A-3199-87CF-560C1B7A4C6D> /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib'

How can I solve this?
I know that I can manually set the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=14.0 environment variable, and, similarly, for tvOS, but when I set both of these with swift create-xcframework, I get:
error: conflicting deployment targets, both 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' and 'TVOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' are present in environment

What can I do to allow compiling against both of these deployment targets to make the package work with older iOS/tvOS versions?
